# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' - CS50W Wiki

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates, cs50

I'm getting this error while trying to create a search function in Django.

This is where I'm having trouble: If the query does not match the name of an encyclopedia entry, the user should instead be taken to a search results page that displays a list of all encyclopedia entries that have the query as a substring. For example, if the search query were ytho, then Python should appear in the search results.

View:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_title = request.POST['q']
        
        content = converter(search_title)

        if search_title is not None:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
                    "entry": content,
                    "entryTitle": search_title
            })

        else:
            entries = util.list_entries()
            search_pages = []
            for entry in entries:
                if search_title in entries:
                    search_pages.append(entry)
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html",{
                "entries": search_pages
                })
```

HTML:

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
                </form>
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anshi\.virtualenvs\storefront-bp3LZ8Cr\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\anshi\.virtualenvs\storefront-bp3LZ8Cr\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Py Projects\CS50 attempt 00\wiki\encyclopedia\views.py", line 70, in search
    content = converter(search_title)
  File "D:\Python\Py Projects\CS50 attempt 00\wiki\encyclopedia\views.py", line 19, in converter
    html = Markdowner.convert(content)
  File "C:\Users\anshi\.virtualenvs\storefront-bp3LZ8Cr\lib\site-packages\markdown\core.py", line 248, in convert
    if not source.strip():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
[21/Dec/2022 02:09:18] "POST /search/ HTTP/1.1" 500 72472
```

Answer (score 0):

Traceback shows that the error is during `content = converter(search_title)`.

So either `converter` has a bug, or `search_title = request.POST['q']` is not a valid search_title.  (None? Null string? )

Try printing / debugging `search_title` or investigate in more detail just what is being POSTed by your client.

BTW, please get tracebacks formatted readably after cut/pasting!